# How can I get Perl 6's run to work on Windows?

Tags: windows, raku

I'm playing with `run` on Windows. Trying it with `dir` doesn't work but maybe I'm missing something:

```
put '-' x 70;
my $p1 = run 'dir', :out;
put "exit code: {$p1.exitcode}";
put $p1.out.slurp(:close);

put '-' x 70;
my $p2 = Proc.new: :out;
put "exit code: {$p2.exitcode}";
$p2.spawn: 'dir';
$p2.out.slurp(:close).say;
```

The output is just the rule and exit code lines:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------       
exit code: 1                                                                 

----------------------------------------------------------------------       
exit code: 1
```

The `dir` works fine with `shell` but that's a different way of doing things. I could do this but that's going through the shell which `run` wants to avoid:

```
my $p1 = run 'cmd.exe', '/C', 'dir', :out;
```

Comment: What versions of rakudo and MoarVM (or other) are you using?

Comment: This issue might be related: https://github.com/skaji/mi6/issues/40

Comment: You do know that Perl5's `system(LIST)` cheats on Windows by falling back to the shell for this very reason, right?

Comment: I don't know much about Windows at all but I'm trying. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavour given that `dir` is a shell command, not an executable.

If you hit <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog and enter `dir`, it will fail for the same reason (unless you happen to have an unrelated executable `dir.exe` somewhere in your path).

Answer (score 0):

That might be [a bug related to libuv's handling of arguments](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=132258). And `dir` is an internal `cmd.exe` command. Not too familiar with Windows myself, but I think it's better to file an issue.